# Change background color of top bar when navigation drawer is opened

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am developing a react-native project. My screens are in white color, but navigation drawer from left in dark grey color, I would like to have the top bar part of the screen also show dark grey when the drawer is opened but still show white when drawer is closed, how to achieve that?

I am using `"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.6"` for my drawer:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName={InitialScreen}
    drawerContent={props => <MyDrawer {...props} />}
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
    }}>
    <Drawer.Screen name="main" component={MainScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

As you can see I am using my custom layout for the drawer content `<MyDrawer />`, there, I set background to dark grey.

The following screenshot shows how it looks like at the moment when drawer is opened.
[image]

Comment: You can also hide the status bar when the drawer is open. Or is that not an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this hook ([Drawer hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#checking-if-the-drawer-is-open)) and the react-native `<StatusBar />` ([React native status bar](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar)) to have it changed easily. Something like that :

```js
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

export function Screen(props) {
  const isDrawerOpen = useIsDrawerOpen()
  return (<>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor={isDrawerOpen ? colors.darkGrey : colors.white}/>
    {props.children}
  </>)
}

export function MainScreen(props) {
  return (
    <Screen>
      ...
    </Screen>
  )
}

export function test() {
  return (
    <>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName={InitialScreen}
        drawerContent={props => <MyDrawer {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="main" component={MainScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: But where to put this code? I don't want to copy paste the `<StatusBar ...>` code in each of my screen component. I tried your code, I get error `Couldn't find a drawer. Is your component inside a drawer navigator?` apparently your code is outside the drawer navigator.

Comment: I also tried put the code for status bar in `MyDrawer` component, it doesn't have any effect to the status bar.

Comment: Didn't think about that MB. You could try wrapping the hook and the status bar in some sort of screen component, and then using it in your different screens ?

Comment: I've udated my answer with my new idea

Comment: thanks however like I said in my previous comment, I don't want to copy paste that same code to each of my screens, I am seeking for a better solution than that.

Comment: You don't have to copy code the whole code, you just encapsulate your different screens with `<Screen></Screen>`, that's what the guys at infinitered are doing : [Ignite bowser boilerplate](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite-bowser/blob/master/boilerplate/app/components/screen/screen.tsx)